# Disable System Error Popup On Run time (DLL Dependencies)

Tags: c++, winapi, system-error

I am working on a WINAPI project which has a few .dll dependencies.
Just for clarification, see below:

```
MyApplication.exe
Util.dll
MySpecialValuable.dll
```

Let's say I took away `MySpecialValuable.dll` from the folder path; I will get a message like this:
[image]
My question is, is there a way I can disable the popup entirely - silently exit? Or somehow hide the name of the .dll inside the popup?
This may seem pointless to most but I do not want to expose the libraries I am using.

Comment: You would have to load the dll at runtime rather than linking to it. It'd still be easy enough to find out the dlls used with tools like dependency walker though

Comment: It's trivial to find out what DLLs your program is using. This is a classic mistake made by people who have incomplete knowledge of the platform. Because you don't know how easy it is to find this information out, you don't realise that it is simple. Don't kid yourself that you can hide this information.

Comment: I understand finding my dependencies could is very very simple -- I just want to prevent these popups that blatantly display the name of the library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot *"silently exit"*. The process hasn't started executing user code when the dialog is displayed by the system. Imports are resolved by the loader prior to executing user code.

While there *may* be ways to configure the system to prevent the error dialog (which I am not aware of), you have other options:

- The obvious one: Ship all your dependencies. As the author you know your dependencies. There won't be any error messages when all imports can be resolved at load time.
- Postpone import resolution until you have a chance to handle failure. Marking the respective DLLs as [/DELAYLOAD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/delayload-delay-load-import) will allow you to do that. See [Linker Support for Delay-Loaded DLLs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/linker-support-for-delay-loaded-dlls) for more information.
- Use [run-time dynamic linking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/dlls/run-time-dynamic-linking).

Make sure you understand, that none of those options will provide a solution to what you are ultimately trying to accomplish. A user could easily enable [loader snaps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/show-loader-snaps) and get full information on every single module that is loaded into your process.

Answer (score 2):

When you don't link to the .dll with an import library but load it during runtime with `LoadLibrary()` you can fail silently.